# Adding a vertex to a model

Tags: mesh, texturing, vertices

I have a car model with many vertices already however some parts of the car which need to be separated as a separate mesh don't have vertices. I tried using extrude, but that doesn't help in moving that specific part of the car.
I need to make it separate meshes to ensure that when I change the texture of the car, some portions are not changed and stay black.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: hello, maybe some pictures would help to understand